# SQL - When would SELECT DISTINCT on more columns result in less results?

Tags: sql, select, distinct

Logically, it makes sense that `SELECT DISTINCT <multiple columns>` should result in equal or greater amounts of output than `SELECT DISTINCT <less columns>`.

I can't use the data I'm actually using, but if an example dataset is:

```
MAKE    |  MODEL  |  YEAR
Toyota  | Camry   | 2017
Toyota  | Camry   | 2015
Toyota  | Corolla | 2016
Toyota  | Corolla | 2016
Honda   | Civic   | 2012
Honda   | Accord  | 2012
```

Then SELECT DISTINCT MAKE should result in 2 rows:

```
MAKE
Toyota
Honda
```

SELECT DISTINCT MAKE, MODEL should result in 4 rows:

```
MAKE    |  MODEL
Toyota  | Camry
Toyota  | Corolla
Honda   | Civic
Honda   | Accord
```

And SELECT DISTINCT MAKE, MODEL, YEAR should result in 5 rows:

```
MAKE    |  MODEL  |  YEAR
Toyota  | Camry   | 2017
Toyota  | Camry   | 2015
Toyota  | Corolla | 2016
Honda   | Civic   | 2012
Honda   | Accord  | 2012
```

The more DISTINCT columns you're selecting on, it seems like the more opportunities for the extra columns to have distinct values and thus possibly increase (but at the minimum, keep the same) amount of rows in the results.

Is there ever a case when SELECT DISTINCT on more columns results in less results? That is what is happening with my case, but I'm not sure if there's a valid reason why that might be.

**EDIT**:

Here is a "copy" of my SQL, except I've changed the table/column names to become generic and removed some extra where clauses for simplicity.

```
WITH view1
AS
(SELECT DISTINCT t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3, t2.column4, t2.column5
FROM TABLE_ONE t1
INNER JOIN TABLE_TWO t2
ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
WHERE t1.column2 = "Name"
AND t2.column3 = 2000
),

view2
AS
(SELECT DISTINCT v1.column1, v1.column2, v1.column3, v1.column4, v1.column5, t3.column6
FROM view1 v1
INNER JOIN TABLE_THREE t3
ON v1.column2 = t3.column2
WHERE t3.column6 = "something"
),

SELECT DISTINCT v2.column1, v2.column2, v2.column3, v2.column4, v2.column5, v2.column6, t4.column7
FROM view2 v2
INNER JOIN TABLE_FOUR t4
ON v2.column4 = t4.column4;
```

When I remove something such as "column5" from all of the above, then it actually returns more results.

Comment: Adding columns to a `distinct` select list should never result in **less** rows, as you noted. There's something else going on here. Could you share the actual query/data?

Comment: if select distinct is being confusing, re-write your query to use `group by`.  It's basically the same thing, but sometimes less confusing as to why it behaves the way it does.

Comment: How about showing us the actual case, rather than an example that doesn't actually replicate the issue?

Comment: the only way I can think of is when the distinct is in a subquery/join. I suppose, if the columns are strings, you can get weird collation/unicode issues is a very rare cases but never has seeing one

Comment: @cHao - I edited it to include what essentially looks like my case.

Comment: @jean - Can you expand a bit on if the distinct is in a subquery/join?

Comment: `Select distinct A, B` is different than `select distinct a, distinct b`, no?

Comment: If you remove `column5` from _all_ of the query, you're also removing `and t2.column5 = 2000`. Removing that condition is of course going to add rows to the result.

Comment: @BrianDewhirst - Not the way I understand it Brian. Fairly confident that distinct applies to all the columns you select

Comment: @cHao - Okay that was a bad example. I randomly changed the t2.<real_column> to column5 just for simplicity's sake. The column that I remove in the SELECT statement is not used for any filtering.

Comment: Apparently it's used for _something_ you're not seeing and/or not disclosing. As mentioned, it's mathematically impossible to add a column to a distinct query, changing nothing else, and get fewer results.

Comment: @cHao - I used "Command F" to find the column in my query and the only 3 times it's used in in the 3 SELECT statements. It's not used in any filtering, which is why I'm so confused.

Comment: I'm confused too; what you're talking about, as you're describing it, simply *doesn't happen*. Even with the query you've provided. Unless you can come up off some more info, there's not much more anyone can do for you.

Comment: @Mureinik - I added in what is essentially my query.

Comment: @cHao - I think my current conclusion is there may be an issue with the internal company service where I'm running my query and outputting results. I noticed the query I outputted above even results in duplicate rows, and I don't see why that would happen given my DISTINCT statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NEVER . A distinct combination of different columns from the dataset can never be less than the unique values of the individual field from the SAME dataset. Its neither possible mathematically nor in SQL . This should hold true irrespective of what you are joining with and other factors .

Comment: Okay that's what I figured. I just wanted to post my thinking out to see if anyone could poke any holes in areas I hadn't thought of, but seems like that's not the case and my issue must be lying somewhere else.

Comment: Can you post the "cars" version of the result you're getting?